# Increasing each element of a set, what is the sum of the medians of the two sets.

Tags: number-theory, median

Consider an ordered set of six consecutive integers in increasing order. To create a new set of six integers, the first, third, and fifth elements are each multiplied by two, and the second, fourth, and sixth elements are each increased by two. The median of this new set of four more than the median of the first set. What is the sum is the median of the first set and the median of the second set?

---

If the first number is $a$, then the six numbers are $a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4, a+5$. I am thinking that we should have two cases, the first number is odd and the first number is even. However, in those cases, I can't figure out the medians of each of the numbers, so that's where I need help.

Comment: Any thoughts?  The usual first step would be to introduce variables and then express the definitions in terms of those variables.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to put my work.

Comment: The median of those $6$ numbers can simply be read off, no?

Comment: $a$ being even and odd won't change anything. Right what the second set is.  Try to list it in order.  Then you will see that the cases that *do* matter are how $2*a$ compares to $(a+ 5)+2$.

Comment: I think the problem, if there is one, might come when you look for the median of the second set...because it may not be clear what order those new numbers come in.  However, except for possibly a few small sets, it shouldn't be hard to work out.

Comment: ... but the median of the first is  $M$ and the median of the second is $M+4$ so you need the order of the second to be so that the median $M+4$ fits.

Comment: Hello! Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* See also the section on titles in [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144).

Comment: Oh yeah, read the problem wrong... So basically the new set is $2a, 2a+4, 2a+8, a+3, a+5, a+7$. I can't tell the median of that set...

Comment: Can anyone help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sequence of numbers is $a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4,a+5$, where $a$ is a positive integer. Let $M_1$ be the median of the old sequence. Note that $M_1=a+2.5$.

The new sequence of numbers is $2a,a+3,2a+4,a+5,2a+8,a+7$. Let $M_2$ be the median of the new sequence.

Note that $2a$ will eventually be bigger than $a+7$, in which case the median will be the mean of $2a$ and $a+7$. Note that

$$2a\ge a+7\quad\text{iff}\quad a\ge7.$$

So if $a\ge7$, then $M_2$ is the mean of $a+7$ and $2a$. So in this case, we'd have that $M_2=1.5a+3.5$. Note that in this case we have that

$$M_2-M_1=0.5a+1\ge4.5.$$

It follows that we must have $a\le6$.

It is now straightforward to check that:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{If }a=1,\text{ then }M_1=3.5&\text{ and }M_2=6.\\
\text{If }a=2,\text{ then }M_1=4.5&\text{ and }M_2=7.5.\\
\text{If }a=3,\text{ then }M_1=5.5&\text{ and }M_2=9.\\
\text{If }a=4,\text{ then }M_1=6.5&\text{ and }M_2=10.\\
\text{If }a=5,\text{ then }M_1=7.5&\text{ and }M_2=11.\\
\text{If }a=6,\text{ then }M_1=8.5&\text{ and }M_2=12.5.
\end{align*}$$

It follows that $a=6$, $M_1=8.5$, $M_2=12.5$, and $M_1+M_2=21$.